# Module load/unload cycle when debugging Delphi application

Tags: delphi, debugging

Sometimes when running application under Delphi 2009 debugger, as soon as I do anything with the application form (click, move..) Delphi starts to flood Event Log with following messages (similar):

```
Module Load: UNKNOWN_MODULE_59954.No DebugInfo. Base Address: $02D90000. Process MyApp.exe (5584)
Module Unload: UNKNOWN_MODULE_59954. Process MyApp.exe (5584)
```

Number of UNKNOWN_MODULE increases for each cycle, so at example there have been almost 60000 module load/unloads.

Application remains unresponsive during this flood. Sometimes I have to just terminate the application to be able to continue.

Any idea how to start tracking the cause of this?

Comment: First of all, find out what `UNKNOWN_MODULE_59954` is. Look for it on your computer.

Comment: SysInternals Process Explorer - filter out everything but OS events and see what DLL was actually loaded. I suspect something like ComCtl from WinSxS

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That number is dynamic, I edited the question to include that.

Comment: that number perhaps is value for THandle returned by Win32 LoadLibrary call

Comment: @Arioch'The Nope, the module handle is `0x02D90000`, i.e. it's the base address.

Comment: sounds like a virus to me, use dependency walker or procmon...

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Virus or virus scanner? I've F-Secure running..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As "Arioch 'The" suggested - download and run [Sysinternal's process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

- From the View menu choose "Lower pane -> DLLs (Ctrl+D)"
- Mark your process in the process tree
- Right click lower pane's header and choose "Add Columns".
- From the DLL tab choose "Base Address".
- Sort modules on that column
- Find your dll's base address - you will get it's name :)

If the module is unloading too fast - set "Options > Difference Highlight Duration" to 9 sec.

In my case it was odbcint.dll:

[image: procMon - find unknown module]

Also give your PC a virus scan - just in case :)

Comment: Great answer. Haven't got change to test this yet (seems to be hard to reproduce when you try it, heisenbug..), but this looks very promising way to get forward with the problem.

Comment: Found it, it was nVidia nView utility program. Disabling it now.